# Not expected results when calling a PostgreSQL function using Dapper

Tags: .net, postgresql, dapper

I have created a simple postgres function that accepts a username and password and returns 1 or 0 depending on if a match was found. I can run the function manually in pgAdmin but when I run the query from my API I don't get a match. I have the postgres logs which look normal to me.

Here is my API call

```
public async Task<bool> AuthenticateUserCredentialsAsync(User user)
{
    
    var dbp = new DynamicParameters();

    dbp.Add("@pusername", user.Username);
    dbp.Add("@ppassword", user.Password);
    
    var response =  await Execute<Results, dynamic>("verify_login", dbp);

    return response.Success;
}

public virtual async Task<T> Execute<T, U>(string functionName, DynamicParameters parameters)
{
    using var dbConnection = GetConnection();
    using var transaction = await BeginTransactionAsync(dbConnection);

    var command = new StringBuilder($"SELECT * FROM {functionName}(");
    if (parameters != null)
    {
        var paramNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var param in parameters.ParameterNames)
        {
            paramNames.Add($"@{param}");
        }
        command.Append(string.Join(",", paramNames));
    }
    command.Append(");");

    try
    {
        var result = await dbConnection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<T>(command.ToString(), parameters, transaction);
        transaction.Commit();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

and I can run this in pgAdmin and get a valid result

```
 SELECT * FROM verify_login('rps', '123');
```

and now here is the postgres log which from my understanding show exactly what I would expect: a username of `rps` and a password of `123`

```
{"timestamp":"2023-06-01 21:15:58.605 CDT", "error_severity":"LOG","message":"execute <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM verify_login($1,$2)","detail":"parameters: $1 = 'rps', $2 = '123'","backend_type":"client backend"}
```

I am expecting `AuthenticateUserCredentialsAsync` to return true with the parameters `rps` and `123` but there may be some disconnect I am not seeing. According to the logs I am sending the right information and I can't find another way to debug this.

Comment: You need to use : for PostGreSql, not @. So it's `paramNames.Add($":{param}");`

Comment: strangely, with this in my `Execute` function this still commits to the postgres log as `"message":"execute <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM verify_login($1,$2)","detail":"parameters: $1 = 'rps', $2 = '123'"`

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems. First of all you need to make clear that it's a function/stored procedure:

```cs
var result = await dbConnection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<T>(command.ToString(), parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, transaction);
```

Then you also need to add the parameters the right way for PostgreSQL:

```cs
foreach (var param in parameters.ParameterNames)
{
    paramNames.Add($":{param}");
}
```

And finally you shouldn't add the `@` in front of the name, not even when parameters are defined with `@`.

```cs
dbp.Add("pusername", user.Username);
dbp.Add("ppassword", user.Password);
```

I don't know enough PostgreSQL to tell you if you should `SELECT` from the function as you do, or just use the name.